# Magento set custom template to render widget instance

Tags: magento, widget

I'm trying to render a widget instance with a custom template. In the admin, in my CMS Homepage, in the Layout Updates XML section I've added the following code:

```
<reference name="right.hp_right_hot_items">
<block type="mih_banner/widget_banner" template="banner/widget/block-right.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

where 'hp_right_hot_items' is the Widget Instance Title, but for some reason the template is not set properly.

In the widget instance fronted properties I've set a layout update:

Display On: Specific Page

Page: CMS Home Page

Block Reference: Right Column

Template: Banner Block Template

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to render a widget with a custom template you have to do the following:

1. Create a yourfile.phtml template on the desired location
2. Create a widget.xml file in yourModule/etc/ and add another value to the template parameters. Ex:

> ```
> <parameters>
>     <template>
>         <values>
>             <block_right translate="label">
>                 <value>{path_to}/yourfile.phtml</value>
>                 <label>Banner Block Template {custom name}</label>
>             </block_right>
>         </values>
>     </template>
> </parameters>
> ```

Now, when you go to admin to add another widget instance, in the layout updates section you should be able to select the template just added.

Answer (score 0):

To set template for block try following action

```
<reference name="right.hp_right_hot_items">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>banner/widget/block-right.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Not working. The widget doesn't show. I'm not sure I'm referencing the widget correctly.